# GLFWwindowsizefun accessibility in OOP

Tags: c++, c, glfw

There is a [glfwSetWindowSizeCallback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gaa40cd24840daa8c62f36cafc847c72b6) function for setting a callback function  [GLFWwindowsizefun](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#gaaca1c2715759d03da9834eac19323d4a) which is called after a GLFWwindow is resized. Now the problem is that in my user interface library I've got a class called `Window` which holds members `GLFWwindow glfw_window;` `glm::mat4 ortho_proj;`, and in the size callback function I want to do `ortho_proj = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)_width, (float)_height, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);`, but I can't because the the callback function is static and is not a member of the `Window` class, and AFAIK it can not be. So the only way I know, for accessing the `ortho_proj` variable in the callback function is making the variable static, but I don't want that, because in that case I would face problems creating multiple windows in a single program.

This is the class definition:

```
class Window
{
    private:
        GLFWwindow* glfw_window;
        mat4 ortho_proj;
    public:
        Window(int _width, int _height, const char* _title);
        bool update();
        void render();
        ~Window();
};
```

This is the *bad* callback function (it would work if ortho_proj would be public and static and if I would add `Window::` before `ortho_proj`)

```
void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* _window, int _width, int _height)
{
    ortho_proj = ortho(0.0f, (float)_width, (float)_height, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

So are there any ways of accessing the the `ortho_proj` variable in the callback function, or maybe the callback function can somehow be a class member? Or are there any GLFW functions returning a boolean if the window has been resized?

Comment: What is the interface you want to allow in your `Window` class. How would you like to be able to customize it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer()`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651) to associate your `Window` pointer with the GLFW window. That way, you can look up the `Window` instance from inside the callback, and call back into the class.

This is a classic pattern, and I would have been majorly surprised if GLFW hadn't supported it. [@elmindreda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142275/elmindreda) knows her stuff.